# CVS check branch existed on cvs server and return true or false

Tags: cvs

I am a newbie in CVS, I just wonder if we can send a command that check the branch I want to create exist or not in CVS Server.

I have found a command that can get all the list of branches:

`cvs log -h 2>&1 | awk -F"[.:]" '/^\t/&&$(NF-1)==0{print $1}' | awk '{print $1}' | sort -u`

 But it sometime take along time to get if the project have alot of branches. Thanks you in advance.

Comment: Why are you wanting to check if it exists? You could try creating the branch and if it fails, take some alternative action.